# SQL Server trigger and INSERTED and DELETED table records

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

When running a batch UPDATE statement (ie. a statement that updates multiple records at once), do the Inserted and Deleted tables contain the same number of records and are the records in the same order (ie. record at pos 0 of Inserted corresponds to record at pos 0 of Deleted)?

Also...

I have an update statement...

```
UPDATE table SET column = value WHERE id = idvalue
```

If originally, the column had a value of 1, and the update sets the column's value = 1 also, both the inserted and deleted tables have one record and the column is flagged as changed (even though it didn't). Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables have no inherent order. If you wish to correlate rows between `inserted` and `deleted`, you're *really* going to want to have an unchangeable key on the table (such as e.g. a surrogate generated by `IDENTITY`). Otherwise, there's no way to identify which rows correspond with each other<sup>1</sup>.

And yes, it's normal for the trigger to fire, and for rows to be present, even when no actual data change occurred.

---

<sup>1</sup>Indeed, there are come optimizations where `UPDATE`s can be decomposed into `INSERT` and `DELETE`s, and then re-composed back into `UPDATE`s which actually "change" different columns - overall, the correct final rows exist in the table, but which *columns* got updated is actually switched around.

Comment: All my tables have a unique key called 'id'. Would it make sense to compare deleted.id with inserted.id?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono - yes, if that `ID` value isn't changeable, then the usual thing to do would be to do a `JOIN` between `inserted` and `deleted` using `ID` on both sides.